# On finding special kinds of power series

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Let $\sum a_n x^n$ be a real power series with finite positive radius of convergence $R$, then is it true that for every real number $s>0$ , we can find a real sequence $\{b_n\}$ (depending on $s$, of course) such  that $\sum b_n x^n$ has radius of convergence $s$ and $\sum a_nb_nx^n$ has radius of convergence $R$ ?

Moreover, can we find a sequence $\{b_n\}$ such that $\sum b_nx^n$ converges everywhere and $\sum a_nb_n x^n$ has radius of convergence $R$ ?

Comment: What if $a_n = 1$?

Answer (score 0):

If you recall how the radius of convergence is defined, you will see that there is a trivial inequality between the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n b_n x^n$ and the product of the radii of convergence of $\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n x^n$ and $\sum_{n\geq 0} b_n x^n$.

Comment: Re: Jack D'Aurizio's comment. Use the Hadamard Radius Formula.